# Directive do not update my scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using a scope all around the application to show a spinner while doing asynchronous requests.

That scope is: `$scope.showSpinner = true / false`

Now I'm working on a directive and the code is this:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('orders').directive('resetOrder', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      var order_id = attrs.resetOrder;
      element.bind('click', function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        alertify.confirm(
          'Warning!',
          'Are you sure you wish to RESET order id: ' + order_id + '?',
          function () {
            scope.showSpinner = true;
            [ ... ]
          }, function () {
            return;
          }
        );
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

`scope.showSpinner` is is not propagated and I don't see the spinner active once pressing the reset button.

What I tried so far:

I converted the `$scope` to `$rootScope`, not worked.
I added `scope.$apply()` and even `$rootScope.$apply()`, not worked.
I wrapped it within `$timeout`, not worked.
I created a scope: { showSpinner: '=' }, not worked.

I can not get out of this issue.
What I'm doing wrong?

Here is how I added the directive in the HTML:

```
<button reset-order="{{ order.id }}">
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Its probably because of scope.showSpinner if your directive is within a child scope.  Try scope.$parent.showSpinner = true to confirm. If this fixes it, you know the cause.

Comment: Not working this solution too... thanks.

Comment: obviously guessing at this point. can you show a short plnkr that demonstrates the issue?

Answer (score 0):

When you're in the callback for alertify.confirm, you're outside of an angular context so any changes to scope properties will not be reflected.

Try:

```
scope.$apply(function () {
  scope.showSpinner = true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It maybe be coused becous your directive has a fatal flaw. You can only use it once within a given scope. You need to create a different controller each time in order to re-use your directive. This is clearly not a great solution.

What you want to be able to do is separate the scope inside a directive from the scope outside, and then map the outer scope to a directive's inner scope. You can do this by creating what we call an isolate scope. To do this, you can use a directive's scope option.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

After isoleting scope add watcher to your directive to monitor changes. Example:

```
scope.$watch('showSpinner', function (newValue, oldValue) {
    if (newValue == oldValue) {
        return;
    }
    //do something
});
```